# If it is the first date or last date use one aggregation; if any other day, use another aggregation

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Let's assume I have the below dataset. 
[image: 1]

What I need to create the below matrix where if it is the beginning or month end, I aggregate A or B in Category 1 and calculate SUM but if it is any other day in a month but 1st or last, I am tagging A or B in Category 2 and calculate SUM. I guess I need to use SWITCH, don't I?

[image]

---

*Edit in info from comments*

Like to create 3 col:

```
isStart = IF ( main_table[date] = STARTOFMONTH ( main_table[date] ), 1, 0 )

isEnd = IF ( main_table[date] = ENDOFMONTH ( 'main_table'[date] ), 1, 0 )

in_between_date =
    IF ( AND ( main_table[date] <> ENDOFMONTH ( 'main_table'[date] ),
               main_table[date] <> STARTOFMONTH ( main_table[date] ) ), 1, 0 )
```

Then, create the columns with my categories, like

```
start_end =
    IF ( OR ( NOT ( ISERROR ( SEARCH ( "A", main_table[code] ) ) ),
              main_table[code] = "B" ),
         "Category 1",
         BLANK () )
```

and

```
in_between =
    IF ( OR ( main_table[code] = "B", main_table[code] = "A" ), "Category 2", BLANK () )
```

But then, what should I use in switch/if ? `= if(VALUES('main_table'[isStart]) = 1`, then what?

Comment: A `SWITCH` should work fine. Or an `IF`.

Comment: @AlexisOlson, like to create 3 col: isStart = if(main_table[date]=STARTOFMONTH(main_table[date]),1,0); isEnd = if(main_table[date]=ENDOFMONTH('main_table'[date]),"1","0"); in_between_date = if(AND(main_table[date]<>ENDOFMONTH('main_table'[date]),main_table[date]<>STARTOFMONTH(main_table[date])),1,0). Then, create the columns with my categories, like start_end = IF(or(Not(ISERROR(SEARCH("A", main_table[code]))),main_table[code]="B"),"Category 1",Blank()) and in_between= if(or(main_table[code]="B",main_table[code]="A"),"Category 2",Blank())

Comment: But then, what should I use in switch/if? = if(VALUES('main_table'[isStart]) = 1, then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You where on the right track but overcomplicated a bit. You only need one extra column "Category" giving for each row in what category the item falls.

```
Category =
    IF (
        startEnd[date] = STARTOFMONTH ( startEnd[date] )
            || startEnd[date] = ENDOFMONTH ( startEnd[date] );
        "Category1";
        "Category2"
    )
```

table end result is:

[image]